# SQL Create View - Sum Transactions on one line

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, view

I want to create a view, whereby all post stock transactions will post on one line, as per my SQL Statement below, I get all transactions, but each is on a new line. I want the arrangement to be each new stock item on a new line, with "QtyOnHand" as the next column. Then I need all the QtyOut transactions to sum up in one column and all QtyIn to sum in another. Is this possible?

```
SELECT 
StkItem.ItemGroup
  ,StkItem.Qty_On_Hand AS QtyOnHand
  ,PostST.TrCodeID
  ,PostST.Description
  ,PostST.Quantity
  ,PostST.Reference
  ,PostST.Order_No
  ,PostST.fQuantityInvoiced
  ,PostST.QuantityR
  ,PostST.TxDate
  ,PostST.Debit
  ,PostST.Credit
  ,Concat(StkItem.Description_1, ' - ',StkItem.Code) AS ItemAndCode 
FROM PostST
 INNER JOIN StkItem
ON StkItem.StockLink = PostST.AccountLink
```

The below picture shows how this statement currently shows - you can see on the far right how the same stock code is repeated for each transaction, as I would rather the stock item show once, and the transactions be summed.

This data will be dumpted into Excel and then used to create a stock turnover report.

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: You need to GROUP BY StkItem.ItemGroup

Answer (score 0):

You have to use SUM() and GROUP BY. Maybe that is what you need

```
SELECT 
StkItem.ItemGroup
  ,SUM(StkItem.Qty_On_Hand) AS QtyOnHand
  ,PostST.TrCodeID
  ,PostST.Description
  ,SUM(PostST.Quantity) as Quantity
  ,PostST.Reference
  ,PostST.Order_No
  ,SUM(PostST.fQuantityInvoiced) as fQuantityInvoiced
  ,SUM(PostST.QuantityR) as QuantityR
  ,PostST.TxDate
  ,SUM(PostST.Debit) as Debit
  ,SUM(PostST.Credit) as Credit
  ,Concat(StkItem.Description_1, ' - ',StkItem.Code) AS ItemAndCode 
FROM PostST
 INNER JOIN StkItem
ON StkItem.StockLink = PostST.AccountLink
GROUP BY 
  StkItem.ItemGroup 
  ,PostST.TrCodeID
  ,PostST.Description
  ,PostST.Reference
  ,PostST.Order_No
  ,PostST.TxDate
  ,StkItem.Description_1
  ,StkItem.Code
```

Comment: Thank you - this decreaes the rows, but the Stock Item still appears more than once. I want it to sum up all transactions in each field per stock item. For example "Blueberry Flavour - DX12045" must only appear once, with transactions next to it.

Comment: The first method above brings upon 17532 lines. However I have 539 stock items in total that are displayed over and over. Ultimately I want to summerise down to just 539 lines (one row per stock item)

Comment: Check if there are some cols with different value that have "Blueberry Flavour - DX12045"

Comment: If you want one row per stock item, you should leave only stock item column and remove other columns except thse you need to sum.